# Legacy GUI - run OnGUI only once

Tags: unity, gui, state

I remember something about onGui being able to be run multiple times per frame, and I also seem to recall that you can check 'which state' the onGUI is being run in, so that you can do all of the intense logic in just the part that gets run once.

Does anybody know what I am talking about --- I can't seem to remember what it was called and it is making googling it a daunting task. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event.html

> "For each event OnGUI is called in the scripts; so OnGUI is
>   potentially called multiple times per frame. Event.current corresponds
>   to "current" event inside OnGUI call."

If you use the Event.current, and look for a given [event type](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.html) in the ongui, then you can have it run once per frame. Namely, looking for the 'repaint' event.

So something like:

```
void OnGUI(){
    if(Event.current.type != EventType.Repaint) return;
    //otherwise if currently painting the gui
    //do all this stuff
}
```